# Javascript Promise.all not show last

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a few functions which return a promise.

There's a start function which executes another function.

As these are promises and I'm using Promise.all, in theory, `Promise.all` should show only after all the other promises are completed.

Here is the code:

```
arr = [];

function start() {
  var aPromiseMain = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myfunction();
    arr.push('start');
    resolve(console.log('I am start'))
  })
  return aPromiseMain
}

start();

function myfunction() {
  var aPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      arr.push('I am myfunction');
      resolve(console.log('I am myfunction'))
    }, 2000)
  })
  return aPromise
}

Promise.all(arr).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

What's happening instead is the order is as follows:

1. I am start
2. Promise.all is showing up
3. I am `myfunction`

It should be:

1. I am start
2. I am `myfunction`
3. Promise.all

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're never putting any of those Promise values into the array; you're just pushing strings.

Comment: The problem is that if I add the string into resolve('I am start'); I can only pass one, so if in the same function I wanted to pass 2 different values in different part of the code I would get issues

Comment: No no; the returned Promise instances are all ignored. Those are the things that need to go into the array, not strings. It has nothing to do with what you pass to `resolve()`.

Comment: your implementation is not correct. Promise.all is where you pass an array of promises. Instead, you are passing an array of string. You don't have to use Promise.all for your current implementation. If you want to do chaining of promises, then you can use Promise.all.

Comment: So basically you are just doing `Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(console.log)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the author's description and comments, it looks like they might need to run the promises in series, so here is an alternative:

```js
arr = [];

function start() {
  console.log("I have started");
  var aPromiseMain = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myfunction().then((result) => {
      console.log('I am finished');
    }); 
  })
  return aPromiseMain
}

function myfunction() {
  var aPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(console.log('I am myfunction'))
    }, 2000)
  })
  return aPromise
}

start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your array should be an array of **promises**, not an array of strings.

```js
arr = [];
    
    function start() {
        var aPromiseMain = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('I am start')
        })
        return aPromiseMain
    }
    
    function myfunction() {
        var aPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('I am myfunction')
            }, 2000)
        })
        return aPromise
    }
    
    arr.push(start());
    arr.push(myfunction());
    
    Promise.all(arr).then(values => {
        console.log(values);
        console.log("I am done");
    });
```

Comment: Well `myfunction()` is called from inside the `start()` function, so that's where the promise would be pushed onto the array.

Comment: the myfunction() promise gets executed twice here, although it's only logged once

Comment: There is some confusion: you are using `promise.all` to execute the promises in parallel, but from your description, it sounds like you need to use `a_promise.then()` to run them in series.  Which one do you need?

Comment: Yes myfunction() is run twice

Answer (score 0):

Your code `arr.push('start');` (for example) simply adds a string to the array. Promise.all needs access to the actual Promise objects, not strings. It cannot do anything useful with strings. Also sending the result of `console.log` as the value to the `resolve` functions makes no sense - the idea of this parameter is to give the listener some data back as a result - console.log logs things, but it doesn't return data.

This example pushes the Promise objects into the array so that Promise.all will wait for each to complete before executing, and also sends a meaningful response when the Promise resolves.

```js
arr = [];


function start() {
  var aPromiseMain = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("start");
    myfunction();
    resolve('I am start');
  });
  arr.push(aPromiseMain);
  return;
}

start();


function myfunction() {
  var aPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("myfunction");
      resolve('I am myfunction');
    }, 2000)
  })
  arr.push(aPromise);
  return;
}

Promise.all(arr).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
});
```